# Differences in JQuery event handling between desktop Chrome/Firefox and the Android 2.3.6 browser

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html5-audio, jquery-events

I am playing around with jQuery and the audio tag, but I ran into some inconsistencies between desktop browsers and the Android 2.3.6 browser.

The bode below just implements customized audio controls through two jQuery mobile buttons with "click" events on the "play" and "pause" buttons associated with the "play()" and "pause()" method calls on the audio element.

The code below works for both desktop Chrome and Firefox as well as the Android 2.3.6 browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#play-button').click( function() {
          document.getElementById('audio').play();
        });
        $('#pause-button').click( function() {
          document.getElementById('audio').pause();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">      
      <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Audio player</h1>
      </div><!-- /header -->  
      <div data-role="content">
    <audio id="audio">
      <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
      <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
      <p>Sorry, your browser does not support playing audio.</p>
    </audio>
    <p>
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align:center">
        <a data-role="button" 
           id="play-button">Play</a>
        <a data-role="button" 
           id="pause-button">Pause</a>
      </div>
    </p>
      </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->

  </body>
</html>
```

while the code below works on Chrome or Firefox but if I load it on the Android browser, no audio plays when I click the "play" button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#player').click(function() {
          if (document.getElementById('slider').value == 'play')
            document.getElementById('audio').pause();
          else 
            document.getElementById('audio').play();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--
    Thanks to  
    http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/
      -->
    <div data-role="page">      
      <div data-role="header">
<h1>Audio player</h1>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content">
    <audio id="audio">
      <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
      <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
      <p>Sorry, your browser does not support playing audio.</p>
    </audio>
    <p>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" 
           style="text-align:center"
           id="player">
        <select name="slider" 
            id="slider" 
            data-role="slider" >
          <option value="play">Play</option>
          <option value="pause">Pause</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
    </p>
  </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea as to why this is the case? Is there a difference in the way events are handled in the mobile browser?

Answer (score 1):

As you're using the JQM release candidate, it's possible you've found a bug..

Click events work standardly in Android.. it's possible your issue regards the way you're handling slider events.. to help isolate the issue and prove events work, does this ultra-basic example work?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var player = document.getElementById('audio');

    $('#play').click(function() {
        player.play();
    });

    $('#pause').click(function() {
        player.pause();
    });

  });
</script>
```

markup change:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" 
     style="text-align:center"
     id="player">
    <a href="#" id="play">Play</a>
    <a href="#" id="pause">Pause</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This simplification does not work on the desktop, nor on the Android browsers (v2.3.6 and v3.2.1), so the behaviour is definitely different.

Comment: if it doesn't work on the desktop or Android than the behaviour (that it fails) is the same, no?

Comment: I meant the behaviour of my code is different from the behaviour of the code you suggested. My code works at least for the desktop, and from my testing your suggestion does not work on either.